# Modified priority queue (with "disabled" elements)

Tags: algorithms, queue

I need something like a priority queue but with the following modification:

Sometimes I need to mark some elements in the queue as "disabled".

Disabled elements:

1. temporarily (until marked non-disabled again) become of less priority than any non-disabled element;
2. are never popped from the queue. That is if the priority queue algorithm leads (because all non-disabled elements are "exhausted" (already popped)) to 
   popping a disabled element, it behaves like as if the queue would be empty and throws an exception instead.

What is the recommended way to implement this? I know only the following solution: Put all elements into a list/vector accordingly the order they come and pop them (by doing an O(N) search) accordingly the priority from the list whenever requested. This may be not the most efficient solution. Is a reasonably easy way to do it more efficiently?

In fact, I need a double ended (modified) priority queue. I write in Python.

It would be too verbose to explain the real situation I need this in, but it is a part of this big project: https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Automatic_transformation_of_XML_namespaces

Answer (score 2):

A priority queue is supposed to be kept sorted. If the elements go changing their priority (mutating) while in the queue they won't be resorted because the queue has no idea they changed.

I'm loath to make any efficiency predictions without a test but of the two solutions I see:

1. Remove, mutate, push (triggering sorting), magically detect as disabled before popping.
2. Remove, push into a different queue named disabled.

2 seems like the better way to go.

Comment: I do not understand both your algorithms "1" and "2". What do you mean?

Comment: @porton What parts of each don't you understand?  Break it down for me.

Comment: "1" What is "mutate"? what is "magically"? etc. "2" If we remove disabled items from the main query, their position (needed when un-disable) is lost

Comment: @porton a priority queue sorts according how an object compares itself with another object. You change that (mutate) after sorting is done (after it's been pushed) and the queue is no longer sorted. Magically means doing this will be a pain because it's reaching past the queues interface/abstraction to ask the object what to do. If you need equal priority items in insertion order [priority queues will break your heart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47969819). These requirements are weird enough to justify making your own collection.